Passenger type Infant with HN status
I'm trying to book a flight in Amadeus with 2 adults, 1 child and 1 infant. The infant is associated with the first adult.
The reservation process is OK (Air_SellFromRecommendation -> PNR_AddMultiElements -> Fare_PricePNRWithBookingClass).
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:awss="http://xml.amadeus.com/ws/2009/01/WBS_Session-2.0.xsd">  <SOAP-ENV:Header><Session xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/ws/2009/01/WBS_Session-2.0.xsd"><SessionId>0DCOUKS0W6</SessionId><SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber><SecurityToken>1T18K54WWWD9P2NSXZ0CTR2CNC</SecurityToken></Session>  </SOAP-ENV:Header>  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
<PNR_AddMultiElements xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/PNRADD_15_1_1A">
    <pnrActions>
        <optionCode>0</optionCode>
    </pnrActions>
    <travellerInfo>
        <elementManagementPassenger>
            <reference>
                <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                <number>1</number>
            </reference>
            <segmentName>NM</segmentName>
        </elementManagementPassenger>
        <passengerData>
            <travellerInformation>
                <traveller>
                    <surname>FATHER</surname>
                    <quantity>2</quantity>
                </traveller>
                <passenger>
                    <firstName>JOHN</firstName>
                    <type>ADT</type>
                    <infantIndicator>3</infantIndicator>
                </passenger>
            </travellerInformation>
            <dateOfBirth>
                <dateAndTimeDetails/>
            </dateOfBirth>
        </passengerData>
        <passengerData>
            <travellerInformation>
                <traveller>
                    <surname>BABY</surname>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                </traveller>
                <passenger>
                    <firstName>OLIVIA</firstName>
                    <type>INF</type>
                </passenger>
            </travellerInformation>
            <dateOfBirth>
                <dateAndTimeDetails>
                    <date>08Apr23</date>
                </dateAndTimeDetails>
            </dateOfBirth>
        </passengerData>
    </travellerInfo>
    <travellerInfo>
        <elementManagementPassenger>
            <reference>
                <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                <number>2</number>
            </reference>
            <segmentName>NM</segmentName>
        </elementManagementPassenger>
        <passengerData>
            <travellerInformation>
                <traveller>
                    <surname>WIFE</surname>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                </traveller>
                <passenger>
                    <firstName>ISLA</firstName>
                    <type>ADT</type>
                </passenger>
            </travellerInformation>
            <dateOfBirth>
                <dateAndTimeDetails/>
            </dateOfBirth>
        </passengerData>
    </travellerInfo>
    <travellerInfo>
        <elementManagementPassenger>
            <reference>
                <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                <number>3</number>
            </reference>
            <segmentName>NM</segmentName>
        </elementManagementPassenger>
        <passengerData>
            <travellerInformation>
                <traveller>
                    <surname>LITLE STORM</surname>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                </traveller>
                <passenger>
                    <firstName>CUTE CHILD</firstName>
                    <type>CHD</type>
                </passenger>
            </travellerInformation>
            <dateOfBirth>
                <dateAndTimeDetails/>
            </dateOfBirth>
        </passengerData>
    </travellerInfo>
    <dataElementsMaster>
        <marker1/>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>11</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>FOID</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>PPQ111111</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>1</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>12</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>FOID</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>ID5555555</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>2</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>13</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>FOID</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>ID222222</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>3</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>21</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>DOCS</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>P-PRY-Q111111-PRY-06Jun89-M-29May26-FATHER-JOHN</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>1</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>22</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>DOCS</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>C-PRY-222222-PRY-23Jan89-F-03Feb30-WIFE-ISLA</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>2</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>23</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>DOCS</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>C-PRY-333333-PRY-15Sep20-F-21Apr31-LITLESTORM-CUTECHILD</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>3</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>21</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>CTCM</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>595981123456</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>1</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>22</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>CTCM</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>595983123456</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>2</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>23</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>CTCM</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>595983123456</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>3</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>24</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>CTCM</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>59598123456</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>4</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>21</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>CTCE</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>johnfather//gmail.com</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>1</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>22</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>CTCE</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>oliviawife//hotmail.com</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>2</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>23</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>CTCE</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>oliviawife//hotmail.com</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>3</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>24</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>CTCE</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>oliviawife//hotmail.com</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>4</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>31</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>AP</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <freetextData>
                <freetextDetail>
                    <subjectQualifier>3</subjectQualifier>
                    <type>6</type>
                </freetextDetail>
                <longFreetext>+595981123456</longFreetext>
            </freetextData>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>41</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>AP</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <freetextData>
                <freetextDetail>
                    <subjectQualifier>3</subjectQualifier>
                    <type>P02</type>
                </freetextDetail>
                <longFreetext>johnfather//gmail.com</longFreetext>
            </freetextData>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
        <dataElementsIndiv>
            <elementManagementData>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>OT</qualifier>
                    <number>51</number>
                </reference>
                <segmentName>SSR</segmentName>
            </elementManagementData>
            <serviceRequest>
                <ssr>
                    <type>DOCS</type>
                    <status>HK</status>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <companyId>YY</companyId>
                    <freetext>C-PRY-4444444-PRY-08Apr23-FI-11Aug33-OLIVIA-WIFE</freetext>
                </ssr>
            </serviceRequest>
            <referenceForDataElement>
                <reference>
                    <qualifier>PR</qualifier>
                    <number>1</number>
                </reference>
            </referenceForDataElement>
        </dataElementsIndiv>
    </dataElementsMaster>
</PNR_AddMultiElements>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

But, the ticket issuance throw an error about infant status (PNR_Reply):
<ssr>
  <type>INFT</type>
  <status>HN</status> <!-- This code must be HK -->
  <quantity>1</quantity>
  <companyId>G3</companyId>
  <freeText>BABY/OLIVIA 08APR23</freeText>
</ssr>

Some agents told me that in this situation they can put some extra entries to the Amadeus system so the infant status changes from HN to HK.
Any help would be appreciated!
